# How to solve fraction polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to figure out how you would solve a problem like this:

$12/(2c+5) = c+1$

I know $c = 81$%,  but I am not sure how to get that to a formula I can use.

I am trying to make a google sheets formula where I can enter the 12,2 and 5 values and figure out the %.

Thanks.

Comment: you already know the value of $c$, so the problem has been solved (what does exactly c=81% mean?)

Comment: Tell us in what context you have to solve this, otherwise we can't help you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $(2c+5),$ and you'll get a quadratic equation:

$12=(c+1)(2c+5)$

$2c^2+7c-7=0$.

This can be solved using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

One of the two solutions is approximately $0.81$, and the other is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is, together with the condition $2c+5\neq 0$, equivalent to
$$
2c^2 + 7c - 7=0.
$$
One also can rewrite this quadratic equation as
$$
(2c + 5)(c + 1) = 12
$$
and divide both sides by $2c+5\neq 0$. The solutions are given by
$$
c=\frac{\pm \sqrt{105}-7}{4}.
$$